# Splitting apache2 logs and moving them

Tags: apache

I have a virtual host, which creates the following access.log:

```
 CustomLog /home/rimmer/dev/fdom/logs/access.log fdom
```

What I want to do, however, is have it split the log to 5 minute increments and move every old log to `/home/rimmer/dev/fdom/logs/complete/access.log-identifier_to_avoid_duplicity`

How can I do this? I think I need to use `rotatelogs`, but I'm not exactly sure how.

**EDIT:** To clarify, I want the logs to be like this:

```
/logs/complete/access.log-17:00-17:05
/logs/complete/access.log-17:05-17:10
/logs/complete/access.log-17:10-17:15
```

While the current log, which is being logged, because the 5 minute increment isn't over yet will be the normal log:

```
/logs/access.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try with [cronolog](http://cronolog.org/features.html). It's an external tool. On a debian install it is available vith a simple apt-get.

You would end up with something like that (the pipe | is very important):

```
CustomLog "|/usr/sbin/cronolog --period='5 minutes' /home/rimmer/dev/fdom/logs/complete/%Y/%m/%d/access.log-%H-%M.log"
```